# How to simulate selection on the first item(or whatever position) in the ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I tried the following but had no luck since the getChildAt always returns null(I am sure the listView is filled).

```
listView.performItemClick(listView.getChildAt(0), 0, listView.getChildAt(0).getId());
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edited: code for adding item into list

```
            lvAdapter = new ActionStreamAdapter<HasDescription>(getBaseContext());
            while ((item = actionStreamQueue.poll()) != null) {
             ...
                lvAdapter.addItem(item);
            }
            ListView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
```

Where *ActionStreamAdapter* is a class extends *BaseAdapter*. The queue is filled by calling the Dao of a simple data sturcure class.

Comment: When are you trying to do this? It's very likely that your ListView is not rendered yet, so it has no children. This would be the case if you're trying to run this in onCreate or onResume.

Comment: No I am not doing that as I have mentioned already.. the ListView is filled for sure. According to Jordi the getChildAt doesn't do what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between childs and items. A Child is a view that is lower in the view hierarchy. For example, when there is a LinearLayout containing two TextViews, then the TextViews are children of the LinearLayout. A ListView has items. These are on the same hierarchical level as your ListView so they aren't children. They are items of the ListView. You should use ListView.getItemAtPosition() instead.

Then, there is a difference between selecting and clicking. Clicking means performing an action on an item and selecting is highlighting it. For selecting the first item, you should do something like: ListView.getItemAtPosition(n).requestFocus()

Comment: Thanks for telling the differences! Actually before I tried the getChild method I tried the getItemAtPosition, but it appears that it returns an Object rather than a View(and cannot be cast into one). Any idea?

Comment: The type of the returned object depends on the Adapter used to bind the list to the data. I can give you a code example on how to make this work if you provide the code of filling the list.

Comment: Edited. So the get item returns the simple object who's class stores a few Strings and longs

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting API where it takes a pointer of the viewitem, typically listview items are recycled so the item at position 0, need not be 0th item on the adapter. You could use findViewWithTagTraversal() to find the view and do the selection on it.

If you don't mind what do you want to do with selection, or do you want to give focus to the first item?

You could use setSelection()

Comment: I actually want to select the first item by default and highlight it..Now I finished the part that when I click on one item it is highlighted and the details will be show on the right side of the activity(Something like Gmail app in tablet).

Comment: Does setSelection does what you want?

Comment: Not really.. setSelection scrolls the list to place the particular item on top(I don't want that), but does not highlight anything. Looks like it's just getting the focus or something

Comment: OK..it's actually silly..but I found that setItemChecked works